# My Relativelayout won't show under FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMvwV.png)OK So, I've made fragment_googlemap.xml and I 've designed FrameLayout as a root layout because I needed to have mapView as a fragment. Cut to the chase, What I wanted to be happened is that to show Spinner and Floating Action Button on the top of google map . But when I run the app, I can't see relativelayout's childs(spinner and floating button). I think it ' s under the googlemapview cause i can see them under googlemap for a sec when it's loading.
Any solution for this?

OOOHH and BTW I Don't Know why elevation attribute's value in floating button doesn't work any Idea please????

Sorry if my english is poor :( And Thx in advance!!!

=======here is my xml file source code below===========

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
        android:entries="@array/location_arraysResc" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/paperplane"
        android:tint="#000000"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="#eF43ef" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Frame Layout must have only 1 child. Put your relative layout and map in another layout before putting in framelayout.

Comment: In Frame Layout Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. So in your case recently added child is mapview that's why your spinner and floating button are behind your map. Reverse the order and it will be fine.

Comment: what would be the best layout ? to put them together?

Comment: @Lcukerd it is not must to have one child but for proper organisation of childs it should have one view.

Comment: Yea reversing the order WOOORKED!!!!!!!! THX!

Comment: You should avoid **nesting layouts**, because it's **bad for performances**.

Comment: use only one layout then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

**1.** `FloatingActionButton` use `app:elevation="6dp"` insted of `android:elevation="6dp"`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
        android:tint="#000000"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="#eF43ef" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
        android:entries="@array/myarray" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: if relative is match parent then map will not show as linear layout's orientation is vertical and the screen space is already covered by relative layout.

Comment: THX! it worked but I see a yellow highlight that keeps telling me this: "@id/fab can overlap @id/map if @id/fab grows due to localized text expansion less... (Ctrl+F1) 
If relative layout has text or button items aligned to left and right sides they can overlap each other due to localized text expansion unless they have mutual constraints like toEndOf/toStartOf"    any suggestion?? srry about my ignorance cause i m new to android : (

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a `FrameLayout` as a `LinearLayout`, except it stacks views on top of each other. The last view in the layout will be the top view on the screen.

So if you want to put something on top of your `MapView`, you should put those view tags *after* the `<MapView>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the `MapView` inside a new `RelativeLayout`, try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
        android:entries="@array/location_arraysResc" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/paperplane"
        android:tint="#000000"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="#eF43ef" />
    </RelativeLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

   </RelativeLayout

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you should actually add map view first and then floating button as a child of frame layout as Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_countries"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fab"
        android:entries="@array/location_arraysResc" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/paperplane"
        android:tint="#000000"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:rippleColor="#eF43ef" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thx for your opinion!

Comment: @poream3387 It's Working Fine As You Expected? or any issue